# List view not responding to click

Tags: android

I have an activity which implements viewpager shown below

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 

  {

    MyAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager pager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final String[] TITLES = {"All", "Popular","Social","departmental","religious","Academics","School","Weekend"}; // title for the tab

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);

}


}


}
```

and in my R.layout.fragment_pager i did this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFE5E5E5" >



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The problem is that I am trying to implement a List View Item Click listener which i used in my fragment layout but it does not respond. shown below

```
  public class SuperAwesomeCardFragment extends Fragment

{

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
private int position;

public static SuperAwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    SuperAwesomeCardFragment f = new SuperAwesomeCardFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position =  getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION) ;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_content_list, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // does not work
        }
    });
    return v;
}

}
```

What could be wrong

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya yes I did

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya yes I did

Answer (score 0):

**Try to implement this code it might be help you.**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Log.e("text","");
            }
        });
```